# Displaying MySQL query in html select

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am still a beginner with php and MySQL. I am having trouble getting rows from my database to display in an html select drop down box. I have researched it and it seems like my code should be good. The campaigns table as a row titled name. This is the row I am wanting to echo into the drop down. The drop down shows, however there is no content in it. Not sure what I am missing here...

### Here is the code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns"); 

echo '<select name="campaignChange">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
}

echo '</select>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` syntax.

You should change:

```
$query = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns");
```

to:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns");
```

and:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
```

to:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

By the way, you should add error handling. If you add this to the top:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

`mysqli` will throw exceptions so you will always know what goes wrong exactly. As long as you use `mysqli` functions of course...

Comment: Changed it to mysqli, still no luck.

Comment: My bad, I also changed the fetch_array to be mysqli_fetch_array. That did the trick, ty!!!

Comment: I will mark as answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks again :D